# select * from types table with empty data records

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Types
ID | Title
1  | blue
2  | red
```

And

```
Colours
ID| patientID | date |Type
1 | 1         | 2019 |1
2 | 1         | 2019 |2
3 | 2         | 2018 |1
```

I need a record even if a type doesnt exist for the record it should bring back null. So patient 2 should bring back 2 records even though there is only 1 record.

```
Select Title,date from Colours Left Join Types On Colours.Type = Types .ID Where patient.ID = 1
{
  patient1:[{
             Title: blue
             date : 2019
           },
           { 
             Title: red,
             date : 2019
           }]
 }
```

However i need patient 2 to bring back all colours with null values for date. Currently getting:

```
Select Title,date from Colours Left Join Types On Colours.Type = Types .ID Where patient.ID = 2
patient:[{
            Title: blue
            date : 2018
         }]
```

However i Need:

```
  patient:[{
             Title: blue
             date : 2018
           },
           { 
             Title: red,
             date : null
           }]
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
select t.Title, c.date
from types t left join
     Colours c
     On c.Type = t.ID and c.patientID = 2;
```